# List with 2 lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I really got crazy wasting all day, searching for this small isue and not being able to find a solution.

I have a list and one of the list items is over two lines. The text in the second line is under the icon. I wonder how I can fix this, so the text goes vertical according to the other lines.

My css is

```
ul.hydro { 

list-style: none;

}

ul.hydro li {
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
color: #898989;

}
```

html

```
<div>
<ul class="hydro">
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Erkundung von Grundwasserbelastungen</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Planungsleistungen zur Sanierung von kontaminiertem Grundwasser</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Hydrogeologische Beratung bei Bauvorhaben (Bemessung von Grundwasserhaltungen)</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Fachgutachten zum Grundwasseranstieg mit wissenschaftlicher Beratung</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Planung von Gebäudeabdichtungen gegen Grundwasservernässung</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Umweltverträglichkeitsuntersuchung im Rahmen der Grundwasserregulierung</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Entwicklung und Steuerung von hydraulischen Maßnahmen zur Grundwasserregulierung</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Entwicklung und Betreiben eines Grundwasser-Monitoring-Frühwarnsystems im Rahmen der Sicherung von Gebäuden und Infrastrukturanlagen</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Grundwasser-Monitoring und Grundwasser-Modellierungen</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Allgemeine Hydrogeologische Studien</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Since the icon is part of the list item's content (and not the list item marker) you'll have to move it from your markup and into your CSS or it will never align properly for various text/screen widths. You can use `background` or `list-style-image`. Sorry I don't have time for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can solve your problem with the use of the `list-style-image` property:

```css
ul.hydro { 
  list-style-image: url('http://placehold.it/10x10');
}

ul.hydro li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #898989;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="hydro">
    <li>Erkundung von Grundwasserbelastungen</li>
    <li>Planungsleistungen zur Sanierung von kontaminiertem Grundwasser</li>
    <li>Hydrogeologische Beratung bei Bauvorhaben (Bemessung von Grundwasserhaltungen)</li>
    <li>Fachgutachten zum Grundwasseranstieg mit wissenschaftlicher Beratung</li>
    <li>Planung von Gebäudeabdichtungen gegen Grundwasservernässung</li>
    <li>Umweltverträglichkeitsuntersuchung im Rahmen der Grundwasserregulierung</li>
    <li>Entwicklung und Steuerung von hydraulischen Maßnahmen zur Grundwasserregulierung</li>
    <li>Entwicklung und Betreiben eines Grundwasser-Monitoring-Frühwarnsystems im Rahmen der Sicherung von Gebäuden und Infrastrukturanlagen</li>
    <li>Grundwasser-Monitoring und Grundwasser-Modellierungen</li>
    <li>Allgemeine Hydrogeologische Studien</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to simply add your own break and then put   before your breaking text. However this is not the best solution it will work. I'll update you with a better fix in a minute.

```
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Entwicklung und Betreiben eines Grundwasser-Monitoring-Frühwarnsystems im Rahmen der Sicherung von Gebäuden und<br>&emsp;Infrastrukturanlagen</li>
```

A way to keep your div from wrapping would be to change the css of your li. Simply add this in and it will prevent the element from wrapping.

```
   li{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

A better solution than the first one that I listed it to add padding and then remove the indentation of the li element. This will keep the start of the sentence in place but when the text wraps around it'll push away from your icon. Add this to your li element and it should do the trick:

```
li{
padding-left: 2em;
text-indent: -2em;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of all of the examples above. Some are commented out so you will need to remove the comments in order to view each example. https://jsfiddle.net/f33xsxov/